# How to show a different text style in latex

Tags: bibtex, keywords

In my paper, I want to write some tool names as how it is written in the `cryptography` and `PyCrypto` words of below image.
[image]

What is the way to write a different style in those words? Is it any command something like \textit?

Comment: Try `\texttt{cryptography}` for the default typewriter/monospaced font. There are other options besides the default. Look [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html).

Comment: Better, some like `\newcommand\package[1]{\texttt{#1}}` in the preamble and then  `\package{cryptography}` in text. So,  if you want to change the style, you only have to change the command definition in the preamble, not every command used in text.